# LP for max stress test

Tags: portfolio-optimization, stress-testing

I'm trying to find a solution to the following problem:

> Assume a portfolio of $n$ zero coupon bonds mapped in risk by their respective DV01. Assume that the ZC portfolio created cannot exceed max and min set DV01 bounds on key maturities (1Y, 2Y, etc.). Also the total DV01 (sum of key maturities DV01) cannot exceed a given level (positive or negative).
>
> Assume we apply a stress vector on each key maturities. Find, for this given stress scenario, the maximum loss the portfolio could suffer from.

This seems like a classic LP problem where the objective function to minimize is the product of the actual DV01s and the stress vector, with constraints being max/min limits on individual DV01 and sum. I am getting the bounds constraints ok but having some difficulty to solve the entire problem with the additional constraint on the sum of DV01s.

Any idea how to solve this?